# Create new tables based on existing tables with different column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have two tables. One is the raw table and another one is the table that I need to reference from. I am not sure how to join this two tables because the structure is different. I am trying to create two new tables based on the reference table. Below is the sample data and expected output:

#Raw table

| Sbjnum | B_01 | B_02 | C_01 | C_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 172009172 | 100 | 120 | 200 | 240 |
| 172009173 | 200 | 140 | 220 | 250 |
| 172009174 | 300 | 150 | 240 | 260 |

#Specnorm

| tablename | fieldname | destfieldname | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Screener | B_01 | Area1 | 1 |
| Screener | B_02 | Area2 | 2 |
| Product | C_01 | ProductID1 | 3 |
| Product | C_02 | ProductID2 | 4 |

Expected output

#Screener table

| Sbjnum | Area1 | Area2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 172009172 | 100 | 120 |
| 172009173 | 200 | 140 |
| 172009174 | 300 | 150 |

#Harvest table

| Sbjnum | ProductID1 | ProductID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 172009172 | 200 | 240 |
| 172009173 | 220 | 250 |
| 172009174 | 240 | 260 |

Comment: In that case, you would need to rely on dynamic SQL to transform `#Specnorm` into something more relational as Dale had previoulsy suggested. Are the values of `fieldname` and `destfieldname` finite as Dale also had suggested? If they are known, it could reduce the complexity of the query by strictly hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build on this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Specnorm;

CREATE TABLE #Specnorm
(
    [tablename] SYSNAME
   ,[fieldname] SYSNAME
   ,[destfieldname] SYSNAME
   ,[sequence] BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO #Specnorm ([tablename], [fieldname], [destfieldname], [sequence])
VALUES ('Screener' ,'B_01', 'Area1' ,   1)
      ,('Screener' ,'B_02', 'Area2' ,   2)
      ,('Product'  ,'C_01', 'ProductID1',   3)
      ,('Product'  ,'C_02', 'ProductID2',   4);

DECLARE @source_data_table_name SYSNAME = '#Raw';
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STRING_AGG(CAST([table_definiton] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';')
FROM
(
    SELECT 'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([fieldname]) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME([destfieldname]) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [sequence]) + + ' INTO ' + MAX([tablename]) + ' FROM ' + @source_data_table_name    
    FROM #Specnorm
    GROUP BY [tablename]
) DS ([table_definiton])

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```